# How specific should type annotations be?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm (relatively) new to TS adoption and very much on board with using it going forward. It definitely seems a great way to augment my existing JS experience. I have a question about type annotations which has been bothering me.

**Example 1**

Suppose I have a `const` which is a string. Not only is it a string, but we know it must be one of a certain set of strings. As I understand it, we would use a union as a type annotation

```
type JobTitle = 'Manager' | 'Supervisor' | 'Burger flipper';
const myJobTitle: JobTitle = 'Manager'; // Setting as 'Cashier' would cause compiler to shout at me
```

**Example 2**

If I take that example to the next stage, what happens if there is only a single permitted value? I quite often export HTTP status codes to use across my applications.

```
// httpStatusCodes.ts

export const UNAUTHORIZED: number = 401;
export const FORBIDDEN: number = 403;
export const NOT_FOUND: number = 404;
```

**Question**

In this scenario, not only do we know these values should be numbers, but we *know* exactly what numbers they should be. Would it be overkill to replace `number` with the specific value (e.g. `export const NOT_FOUND: 404 = 404;`) in this instance?

On the one hand, this feels a bit redundant, but on the other, I get the impression that TS encourages us to be as specific as possible with these things, as it not only aids development but acts as documentation as well.

My other thought is that `404` isn't a type, but rather a *value*, so it shouldn't be used as an annotation (despite the fact that it makes the code stricter and more explicit)

Like I said, still pretty new to this TS world, so just trying to get a feel for where the lines are generally drawn on these things.

Comment: Personally, specifying a single number in a value that's already a constant feels a bit overkill. But this is more like a code-style choice and as long as you're consistent either is probably fine.

Comment: Usually, when I set primitive values to variables (constants especially), my editor warns me that the type definition ":number" is redundant as it inherits the type from the value itself. But, when you work with typescript, it is always a good practice to strictly type everything possible. That's also a good practice when working with other people who might know what kind of variable you are going to declare.

Comment: You should also be able to `export const NOT_FOUND = 404 as const` to infer a strict literal value without repeating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option for doing similar things will be typescript enums, and if you need to specify type for variable holding that simply use enumName

Comment: I see, so we could use

```ts
enum HttpStatusCodes {
 'UNAUTHORIZED' = 401,
        'FORBIDDEN' = 403,
 'NOT_FOUND' = 404,
}

export const UNAUTHORIZED = HttpStatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED;
export const FORBIDDEN = HttpStatusCodes.FORBIDDEN;
export const NOT_FOUND = HttpStatusCodes.NOT_FOUND;
```

That sort of looks like what I was after (enforcing not only the type, but the specific value for the `const`). Thanks

Comment: @SimonHudson there's no need to export enum members separately - just export the whole enum and import it instead of specific codes. It will make your imports shorter and every reference - more explicit. (and member names shouldn't be quoted)